# Is there anything wrong with my NSUserDefaults load operation?

Tags: iphone, ios

Everything is working as expected however I just wanted to make sure I am doing this properly:

```
NSString * uName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key1"];
NSString * pWord = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key2"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the below if you are storing only `NSString` for **key1** and **key2**.

```
NSString *myString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

For more read the blog post for using of `NSUserDefault`.

[iPhone Programming Tutorial – Saving/Retrieving Data Using NSUserDefaults](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

Comment: does stringForKey have an advantages over objectForKey?

Comment: @jini : Yes it has because it's a common method to access any value stored using NSUserDefault regardless of their type, But stringForKey is only used to access the value stored as NSString.

Comment: Yes, there is an advantage if you are a bonehead and change the type of what you are storing to key1 (eg. was NSNumber and now is NSString, will return nil vs an NSNumber instance). But you wouldn't do that, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. That's how to read an object from user defaults.

`- (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)defaultName` will also do the same thing with more static typing.